# React Native: Move android, ios package to non-root path

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to modify default react-native package structure to something like this:

```
root
    |--- .babelrc
    |--- node_modules
    |--- src
           |--- app
                  |--- package1
                            |--- package2
                                       |--- android/
                                       |--- ios/
                                       |--- index.ios.js
                                       |--- index.android.js
```

Can someone give me pointers to get this working?

Comment: I think you will have to modify 'react-native-cli' to achieve this. Curious to know. Why do you need to change the react-native project structure? What is the advantage of using this this structure compare to the default one?

Comment: I have a complex project that has multiple react & react native apps sharing code. Therefore, I need a structure like this